# Thrust: How to returns indices of active array elements

Tags: cuda, thrust

How can I use thrust to return the indices of active array elements i.e. return a vector of indices in which array elements are equal to 1?

Expanding on this, how would this work in the case of multi-dimensional indices given the array dimensions?

Edit: currently the function looks like this

```
template<class VoxelType>
void VoxelVolumeT<VoxelType>::cudaThrustReduce(VoxelType *cuda_voxels)
{
    device_ptr<VoxelType> cuda_voxels_ptr(cuda_voxels);

    int active_voxel_count = thrust::count(cuda_voxels_ptr, cuda_voxels_ptr + dim.x*dim.y*dim.z, 1);

    device_vector<VoxelType> active_voxels;

    thrust::copy_if(make_counting_iterator(0), 
                    make_counting_iterator(dim.x*dim.y*dim.z),
                    cuda_voxels_ptr,
                    active_voxels.begin(),
                    _1 == 1);
}
```

Which is giving the error

```
Error   15  error : no instance of overloaded function "thrust::copy_if" matches the argument list
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine `counting_iterator` with `copy_if`:

```
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
...
using namespace thrust;
using namespace thrust::placeholders;

copy_if(make_counting_iterator<int>(0),
        make_counting_iterator<int>(array.size()), // indices from 0 to N
        array.begin(),                             // array data
        active_indices.begin(),                    // result will be written here
        _1 == 1);                                  // return when an element or array is equal to 1
```

Comment: Okay, I've tried that, but I'm getting the error


`Error 15 error : no instance of overloaded function "thrust::copy_if" matches the argument list

Comment: Cool, that looks like its working. Is there any documentation as to how the `thrust::placeholders` work? Also, whats the best way to make a 3-dimensional iterator that iterates along with the 1-dimensional iterator. i.e. I want to know the 3-dimensional coordinates, but it seems wasteful to convert back to a single index simply to access the linear memory.

Comment: @ragnar: Perhaps you can use a `transform_iterator` to transform the linear index into multidimensional coordinates.